# Highlighting search patterns

Tags: content-management-system, alfresco, highlight

I used alfresco to search file contents, but it is not highlighting search patterns it is just showing the file in which the content is there. I need a open source CMS in which the test highlighting is supported. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of documents is this for? Only highlighting a text file is a lot lot easier than trying to highlight inside a word document...

Comment: @Gagravarr I asked in alfresco forum, a user said that it is doable but he didnt explain much [link](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/end-user-discussions/alfresco-explorer/how-show-contents-files-when-searching-alfresco#comments)

Comment: Alfresco turns your documents into plain text, then indexes that. If you want to highlight the search result inside the plain text version, it's possible with a bit of work. Highlighting inside the original is just about possible, but would involve a log lot more work, using things like Apache POI and Apache PDFBox

Comment: @Gagravarr okay is there any way to highlight the plain text converted by alfresco

Comment: Out of the box, no. With some work, sure, as Jeff said in the forum post. Look for any good Lucene Highlighting tutorial and basically follow that

Comment: @Gagravarr can I use solr highlighter and integrate with alfresco to display the texts

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?